# Can I count on thread affinity in an ASMX web service app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, thread-safety, asmx

I have an "enterprisey" project which has many, many layers.  A WinForms client connects to the web service, which calls the business layer, which calls the translation layer from another system, which in turn calls several more wrappers to finally update a value.  No joke - that's what 12 years of continuous development will do.

I now must pass an ID from the client all the way to the database layer.  The ID must travel with **every single request**.  My initial thought was to plumb it all the way through, but that would be ridiculously time consuming and next to impossible (there is a massive amount of static insanity pretty much all the way down).

So I am thinking of assigning this ID to `ThreadLocalStorage` in the `Application_BeginRequest` of the ASP.NET Web Service app.  And then the last library to talk to the database can read this value and pass it to the DB.

My question is this: can I count of thread affinity from the `Application_BeginRequest` all the way to the last library in the chain?

Comment: As long as you're not leveraging the threadpool, etc.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN. Bottom line: I wouldn't depend on it for _anything_ much less would I depend on undocumented behavior.

Comment: @JohnSaunders This is not new development.  As my question stated, it's been worked on for the past 12 years.

Comment: All the more reason to not expect an old dog to learn new tricks.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Are you suggesting that I rewrite the entire thing using a new shiny technology so that I can pass a single ID through the system?

Comment: WCF isn't the "shiny new technology". It's seven years old. About time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd better off using [HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx).

If you ever decide to use asynchronous pages `HttpContext` (inclding Items) will properly move to new thread, but normal TLS not.

Note that if you are not relying on ASP.Net thread management (i.e. creating own threads/using threadpool/or any methods like  `.ParallelFor`) than you will need to make sure you carry context to new threads correctly (i.e. assign HttpContex.Current early in operation on the new thread). If you ever expect multiple threads to handle single request at the same time I'd recommend not to go with `HttpContext.Items`.

Comment: That's a good idea.  My problem is that library at the very bottom of the stack is being used by non-web clients as well. They'd have difficulties creating HttpContext.Items objects (tell me if I am wrong).

Comment: I am not creating any threads, not using ThreadPool either.  How exactly would multiple threads handle the same request?  Not sure I follow you.

Comment: @AngryHacker - if you use [`.Parallel.For`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.for.aspx) during your request than multiple threads may need to access information about "current request" at the same time...

Comment: @AngryHacker on TLS may be fine - you may need to review code if indeed there is no multiple threads involved... If you don't use asynchronous page than single request is served by single thread from start to end.